# Trying to create directory on another machine , getting exceptions

Tags: c#, authentication, directory, remote-server

here is my code :

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP = null;
Stream ftpStream = null;

string currentDir = string.Format("ftp://{0}", "10.10.10.46/E:/SERVER");
//string currentDir=string.Format("ftp://{0}","10.10.10.21/var/www/webdav/SERVER");


reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(currentDir);
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("core", "c0relynx");
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
ftpStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Whenever I execute this code I get the exception "System error".

If I use the url "10.10.10.21/var/www/webdav/SERVER" I get the exception "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in".

10.10.10.46 is a windows PC and 10.10.10.21 has Ubuntu.

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong and what I must do to resolve this?

Comment: [superuser](http://superuser.com/) would probably a better spot for this kind of question. It looks like you have permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself is not the problem.  It's not how I generally do things, but it does work for me on my test rig.  The problem is most likely related to the server configuration and/or credentials.

The `(530) Not logged in` error is almost always because your credentials are wrong.  Check that the username and password are correct for the Ubuntu server by using a standard FTP client like Filezilla or even the Windows command-line ftp client.

As for the other message, it is most likely a generic `500` response returned by the other server.  There are too many possible reasons for this and not enough information.

The only thing I can suggest is again to try the operation with the same credentials in some other FTP client to see what is actually happening.  Unless you're keen to use a packet trace, and know enough about the FTP protocol to understand what the packets are telling you.

At this point you're going to have to do some diagnostics on the FTP server, which is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  The [superuser](http://superuser.com) site is better suited for this.